# Is there any benefit in wrapping a `String` with a `new String (...)` before running its methods?

Tags: java, string

I saw a few old code snippets in a piece of software that no one remembers who wrote that instead of doing something like:

```
String abc = SOME_CONSTANT.toLowerCase()
```

They do:

```
String abc = new String(SOME_CONSTANT).toLowerCase()
```

I can't see any value in this - seems like plain old bad programming (e.g. not understanding that String is immutable). Anyone can see a **good** reason for this?

**Note:** SOME_CONSTANT is defined as -

```
public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "Some value";
```

Comment: You are correct... the worst kind of 'bad' programming... people who don't understand basic concepts, but think they have mastered them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only point in wrapping a String inside another String is to force a copy. e.g.

```
String str = "A very very log string .......";
// uses the same underlying string which we might not need after this.
String str1 = str.substring(0, 1); 
// take a copy of which only has one char in it.
String str2 = new String(str1);
```

---

I would just do

```
public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "Some value";
public static final String LOWER_CONSTANT = SOME_CONSTANT.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Why not just `public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "some value";` ?

In any case, looks like the code needs it sometimes in upper and sometimes in lower case ... god knows why

Comment: This would change the constant itself, which is not likely what the OP had in mind. Perhaps other places need `SOME_CONSTANT` to have the case as defined.

Comment: You could even String.intern() the LOWER_CONSTANT result.

Comment: Interresting, but not valid for this case, a new string is require because of toLowerCase anyway.

Comment: Yes, in theis case we do not have a program using the constant anyway, so we could even skip declaring them. But otherwise the same String may be interned in some other context or even be the same as SAME_CONSTANT which I assume will have another value in the real application ;-) I have seen many cases where .lowercase(), null checks etc. are made just to be sure even if this was done 5 lines of code before.

Answer (score 4):

No, it just creates more objects (unless the compiler optimizes it away)

Comment: It fact it has a subtle effect concerning synchronization. Because any object can be used to synchronize, copying an object would prevent outside code from synchronizing on the same instance and thus potentially produce deadlocks. Combined with the string cache, this is famous bug that occured on some old version of libraries bundled together. (I think it included hibernate, but not sure). But this is very specific, and no one should synchronize on an immutable object anyway, it has no sence.

Comment: You can't be 100% sure you get a new object -- the compiler knows strings are immutable.  In C#, I can confirm that you would not end up with a new string object -- I've seen this specific technique used to synchronize different string objects (but the same string) and fail on .NET.  I'm not sure what Java would do, but I wouldn't count on it.  Better to use an Object or other type.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you: it's bad programming

Answer (score 3):

No good reason. As you said, String is immutable, so calling `toLowerCase()` on it will always produce a new string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
new String(someString)
```

only makes sense in one important case:

```
String s = incredilyLongString.substring(1000,1005);
String t = new String(s);
```

assume incredilyLongString is 1000000 chars long (e.g. an XML file) and you just want 5 chars of it. The String s will still take at least ONE MEGABYTE of memory, but String t will be created from scratch and so will take up only the necessary memory.

Comment: The string `s` will contain a reference to the `char[]` stored inside the original `incredilyLongString` - it will not duplicate it. So as long as both Strings are still referenced, the memory will not be an issue. Only once you loose the reference to the `incredilyLongString` will you get a value from it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think when you use `new String()` you force the JVM to create a new object for that String. If you use `SOME_CONSTANT.toLowerCase()` JVM will search in the pool of Strings and just make a reference if there is a same String.

Maybe use `new String()` in this case can be a good practice just to makes clear that the `toLowerCase()` will affect just the new String generated, not the constant.

But anyway, the effect is the same

Comment: Strings are immutable - `toLowerCase()` creates a new instance anyhow, it does not effect the constant ever.